# Inserting if record not exist, updating if exist

Tags: laravel-5

Hiii
I have 2 database tables with the columns table :1 "id, invoice_id, subject, total" table:2 "id, invoice_id, item_name, price".whenever i try to update record with the help of invoice_id if record doesn't exist in item table it will not insert new item in item table.

here i attached my JSON data

```
{ 
"date": "2019-06-08", 
"client_id": "1", 
"currency_id": 4, 
"total_amount": null, 
"subject": "RD Management", 
"items": [
{ 
"item_name": "Saving",
"price": "500"
}, 
{ 
"item_name": "Fix",  
"price": "500"
},
{ 
item_name": "Current", 
"price": "200"
} 
]
}
```

here one problem is also
my JSON can not send item_id also
so without item id how can i update my record...???
here 3rd item is not present in my table

here is my controller

```
foreach ($request->items as $key => $items) 
{
$item_update = [
'item_name'    => $items['item_name'],
'price'  => $items['price']
];
DB::table('items')
->where('invoice_id', $id)
->update($item_update);
}
```

I Except output like this

```
"items": [
{
"id": 1,
"invoice_id": "1",
"item_name": "Saving",
"price": "500",    
},
{
"id": 2,
"invoice_id": "1",
"item_name": "Fix",
"price": "500",      
},
{
"id": 3,
"invoice_id": "1",
"item_name": "current",
"price": "200",       
},
]
```

but my actual output is

```
"items":[
{
"id":"1"
"item_name": "Fix",
"price": "500",       
},
{
"id":"2"
"invoice_id": "1",
"item_name": "Fix",
"price": "500",       
}
]
```

this output override item_name at update time.
there are any way to solve this both problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't identify which items already exist and which ones are new, your remaining option is to identify items by `item_name`+`invoice_id`. The downside is that you cannot update `item_name` this way.

If you have Eloquent models properly set up, you can use `updateOrCreate()`.

```
<?php
foreach ($request->items as $key => $items) 
{
    $itemAfterUpdate = App\Item::updateOrCreate(
        [ 
            'invoice_id' => $id, 
            'item_name' => $items['item_name'] 
        ], 
        [ 'price' => $items['price'] ]
    );
}
```

If not, you will basically have to do what Eloquent does behind the scenes, which is check if the item already exists based on `item_name` and `invoice_id`, and then insert or update accordingly.

```
 <?php
    foreach ($request->items as $key => $items) 
    {
        $alreadyExists = DB::table('items')
            ->where('invoice_id', $id)
            ->where('item_name', $items['item_name'])
            ->exists();
        }
        if($alreadyExists){
            DB::table('items')
                ->where('invoice_id', $id)
                ->where('item_name' => $items['item_name'])
                ->update(['price' => $items['price']);  
        }
        else{
            DB::table('items')->insert([
                'invoice_id' => $id, 
                'item_name' => $items['item_name'],             
                'price' => $items['price']
            ]); 
        }

    }
```